# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<Object*>&’

Tags: c++, vector, g++

I've *just* started out with C++ because I want to translate my raytracer from Python into C++.

Anyways, I'm trying to compile my raytracer with `g++`, and I get this error:

```
In file included from engine.cpp:10:0:
objects.cpp: In function ‘Vector Trace(Ray&, std::vector<Object*>&, float, int)’:
objects.cpp:97:30: error: conversion from ‘Object*’ to non-scalar type ‘Object’ requested
objects.cpp:110:29: error: conversion from ‘Object*’ to non-scalar type ‘Object’ requested
engine.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
engine.cpp:36:55: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<Object*>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<Object*>*’
objects.cpp:86:8: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘Vector Trace(Ray&, std::vector<Object*>&, float, int)’
```

I know all of these errors revolve around my `objects` variable, as I'm not really sure how to make arrays of objects and use it properly from within functions.

Here's part of my `main()`:

```
vector<Object*> objects;

Sphere sphere = Sphere();
sphere.pos = Vector(0, 0, 0);
sphere.radius = 1;
sphere.diffuse = Vector(1, 1, 1);

objects.push_back(&sphere);
```

And the deceleration of `Trace()`:

```
Vector Trace(Ray &ray, vector<Object*> &objects, float roulette, int n = 0) {
```

`Sphere` is declared like so:

```
class Sphere: public Object {
  public:
```

I'm not really sure what to do, as I've tried tweaking just about everything about that `vector<>` thing!

**EDIT**

Here's line **97**:

```
Object target = objects[i];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include the line that have problems.

In `objects.cpp:97` you're doing something like this:

```
Object x = objects[0];
```

This won't work, as `objects` is a vector of `Object *`

Use e.g. one of these:

```
Object * x = objects[0]; // x points to the actual Object in your vector
Object x = *objects[0]; // x is a copy of the Object in your vector
Object & x = *objects[0]; // x is a reference to/alias of the actual Object in your vector
```

On the second error, you try to pass a `vector<Object*> *` where a `vector<Object*>` is expected. Don't pass `&objects` but rather just `objects`

Comment: `Object target = *objects[i];` fixed that error, thanks! Now, only the `Trace()` function remains. GCC doesn't like my `vector<>` parameter at all...

Comment: @Blender: The error is likely that you pass `&objects` to Trace - remove the `&`